# How to Burn Tokens from someone wallet

Tags: tokens

Like e.g I created a token and sent it to the wrong contract address how to burn the token from the wrong contract address

Comment: What token standard are you using? For most token contracts this is not possible unless you implement it manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can't burn tokens from other addresses/contracts unless that address/wallet approves you to do it. See the [ERC20 approve method](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. If the contract do not have built-in transfer method for that token, the tokens will stay there **locked** forever. The contract cannot recognize the incomming tokens, if it's not built that way. This is how so many ERC20 tokens are currently locked. And this is why standard ERC223 appeared and is trying to fix these problems.

Comment: https://etherscan.io/token/0xa7c8d7a1c894e51dbb7c680b5b1dbdc845bfbdab

Comment: What of this contract